# Retrieving recorded images stored in AXIS recorder located in remote area

Tags: axis, onvif, vapix

I am planning to buy and use [AXIS Camera Station S2208 Appliance](https://www.axis.com/products/axis-s2208)
, and seeking way to retrieve images stored in this recorder in remote area via API. (not retrieve from camera, but recorder)

I guess VAPIX (or ONVIF) API is responsible for this task, but not sure where the exact description is (I looked over [VAPIX-library page](https://www.axis.com/vapix-library/), but found no clue).

Questions are as follows

1. To begin with, is it possible to retrieve images from recorder via VAPIX (or ONVIF) ?
2. If it is possible, where is the description in [VAPIX-library page](https://www.axis.com/vapix-library/) (from `Network video`, `Applications`, `Audio systems`, `Physical access control` or `Radar`)?
3. If not, are there any ways to do it?

I also searched in [AXIS Camera Station User Manual](https://www.axis.com/products/online-manual/34074), and found out Developer API. However, it was not clear to me about details.

I posted here because I couldn't get answer from official page. 
Any help would be great. Thanks!